# mySQLi --> Is it possible to create a query that would calculate the sum between dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, sum

I have a mySQL table that contains at least the following field:

```
ID | user | date | balance
```

I would like to know if it is possible to sum the column balance group by user for dates that are between the following cases:

- between TODAY and TODAY + 30days
- between TODAY+31days and TODAY+60days
- above TODAY+61days

Query:

```
SELECT user, SUM(balance) AS sumBalance
FROM table
WHERE ... CASE << this is where I think I need help...
GROUP BY user
```

It may not be possible to do all that once is the same query. If not I can execute three separate query and fill an array.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    user,
    sum(case when date between current_date and current_date + interval 30 day then balance end) balance1,
    sum(case when date between current_date + interval 31 day and current_date + interval 60 day then balance end) balance2,
    sum(case when date >= current_date + interval 61 day then balance end) balance3
from mytable
where date >= current_date
group by user
```

This gives you one record per `user` (which, by the way, is [a MySQL keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html), hence not a good choice for a column name), with 3 additional columns that contain the sum of `balance` for the three distinct `date` ranges.